# Blazor Server works fine in Visual Studio but fails when deployed to IIS

Tags: visual-studio-2019, iis-8, blazor-server-side, .net-5

I have a Blazor Server app that is not far off the template Blazor app that VS generates. It works fine in VS using IIS Express. But when I publish it to a remote IIS server I get this error page

[image]

This is the traffic when I try and load the site.

[image]

Any help or ideas on how to fix this are appreciated.

Comment: Have you installed the .NET Core hosting bundle? If IIS wants to host Blazor Application, you must install .NET Core hosting bundle.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sort this out. I deleted everything on the site and published it again. Not sure why this worked but it did.